# associate multiple post with one post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, content-type

I am creating a meta_box in my content type "Teams" in the admin area that allows the users to check a box next to any of the titles they want to associate with the content they are creating. The titles are being looped they are from a different content type.

```
  array(
    'name' => __('Player List', 'theme_name'),
    'desc' => 'Select all the players that are on the team you are creating.',
    'id' => 'theme_name_players_completelist',
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => array(
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'players');
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        array('name' => __(the_title(), 'theme_name'), 'value' => 'get_the_ID()'),
      //But here is where I need to loop through and show the titles of the content type called team_members. The value could be the post ID or Title or whatever I guess.
         endwhile;
    )
  ),
```

Is this the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can build an array like this, but it can be simplified to (untested):

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'players') );
$options = array();

if( $posts ) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $options[$post->ID] = $post->post_title;
    }
}

$the_array = array(
    'name' => __('Player List', 'theme_name'),
    'desc' => 'Select all the players that are on the team you are creating.',
    'id' => 'theme_name_players_completelist',
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $options
  );
```